# monitoring application (CPU and cache usage) on single Linux box with 80 cores

Tags: performance

I am looking for a performance monitoring tool for my application which will collect/visualize in realtime the CPU and cache usage on single Linux box like IBM System or HP ProLiant with typical configuration  8 processors / 80 cores.
 Application is the home-grown multithreaded C+ code which uses OpenMP.
This monitoring tool should not run 24 hours per day; it should not do e-mail notification.
I will run this  tool just before sending commands to my apps, the apps will execute the command (it may take as a maximum few minutes only). During this time interval I need to analyze:

```
 - usage of cores
 - data movement between processors 
 - usage of L1, L2, L3 caches
 - some other metrics (help me here) which can help to find bottleneck in application 
 performance and resource utilization
```

I guess that tools like Nagios / Zabbix are too heavy for this task.
From another side using the command-line tools like "top" and "sar" for 80 cores not very convenient and plotting (not necessary real-time)  would be nice to have...

Comment: What you're looking for falls under the domain of application profiling rather than system monitoring. I think it would be far more topical on SO.

Answer (score 1):

While getting the per core usage is rather easy - the other values might prove to be not practical, not at least without running that application within a profiler of some sorts.

Measuring QPI utilization is something highly non-trivial if at all possible. Intel's vTune might be able to acquire such things but only when running instrumented version of your binaries.

Also on x86 there is no way to figure out L1,L2,L3 usage of any kind - you can grab the low level CPU counters to measure cache misses though (but would probably need to use instrumented/profiled binaries and always withan something like vTune or PAPI).

You could "easily" setup something to pull all the lower level performance counters into SNMP and grab the SNMP values via standard SNMP capable monitoring tools but be aware that SNMP pulling is something that you don't want to occur more than 1-2/s max. Or pull that info into something like `collectd`.

I'm also having the impression that you don't understand the problem domain of monitoring tools. They are not ment to be used as low level analysis probes for finding application level/system bottlenecks - at best you could get some hints which resource (from a 10K feet view) is running under full utilization. Monitoring and alterting tools are something that operations staff needs to use to understand which part of their IT system is currently used and how, to gather historical data and predict future resource utilization and to be alerted when something breaks.

Comment: The priority in answering a question is to move the questioner closer to achieving their goal; not to assert what you think is impossible. Unless our opinion is requested,  reliably sourced information is far more desirable than our opinions, so let's aim to provide the former instead of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

SiteScope, Hyperic or any combination of shell scripts, native OS utilities and a DB to store the results may do the job.